# Get mapping of categorical variables in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing this to make categorical variables numbers

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['good', 'bad', 'good', 'great']}, dtype='category')

       x
0   good
1    bad
2   good
3  great
```

How can I get the mapping between the original values and the new values?

Comment: Can you post some raw input data and code to construct your df so we can reproduce your data

Answer (score 92):

#### Method 1

You can create a dictionary mapping by enumerating (similar to creating a dictionary from a list by creating dictionary keys from the list indices):

```
dict( enumerate(df['x'].cat.categories ) )

# {0: 'bad', 1: 'good', 2: 'great'}
```

#### Method 2

Alternatively, you could map the values and codes in *every* row:

```
dict( zip( df['x'].cat.codes, df['x'] ) )

# {0: 'bad', 1: 'good', 2: 'great'}
```

It's a little more transparent what is happening here, and arguably safer for that reason.  It is also much less efficient as the length of the arguments to `zip()` is `len(df)` whereas the length of `df['x'].cat.categories` is only the count of unique values and generally much shorter than `len(df)`.

#### Additional Discussion

The reason Method 1 works is that the categories have type Index:

```
type( df['x'].cat.categories )

# pandas.core.indexes.base.Index
```

and in this case you look up values in an index just as you would a list.

There are a couple of ways to verify that Method 1 works.  First, you can just check that a round trip retains the correct values:

```
(df['x'] == df['x'].cat.codes.map( dict( 
            enumerate(df['x'].cat.categories) ) ).astype('category')).all()
# True
```

or you can check that Method 1 and Method 2 give the same answer:

```
(dict( enumerate(df['x'].cat.categories ) ) == dict( zip( df['x'].cat.codes, df['x'] ) ))

# True
```

Comment: it is saying this AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'cat'

Comment: Can you be more specific?  It sounds like you tried to use `cat` on a column that is not a categorical.  You can check the dtypes with `data.info()` and can convert almost any column to categorical with `astype('category')`.

Answer (score 14):

Hier is my solution based on the Matheus Araujo's answer.

Let's say we have a country column. First, you must convert your column to categorical data type:

```
df.country = df.country.astype('category')
```

Get codes for each value as an array:

```
df.country.cat.codes
```

Convert the codes array back to strings

```
df.country.cat.categories[df.country.cat.codes]
```

You can also pass a list of integers

```
df.country.cat.categories[[0, 1, 2]]
```

Or a single code

```
df.country.cat.categories[0]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you run this:

`df["column_category"].cat.categories.get_loc("item")`

It will return the code (e.g 0) that corresponds to the "item" in the mapping.

If you run this:

`df["column_category"].cat.categories[0]`

It will return the value of the code (e.g "item") that corresponds to the position 0 of the mapping