# pandas get mapping of categories to integer value

Tags: python, pandas

I can transform categorical columns to their categorical code but how do i get an accurate picture of their mapping?  Example:

```
df_labels = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'col2':list('abcab')})
df_labels['col2'] = df_labels['col2'].astype('category')
```

df_labels looks like this:

```
   col1 col2
0     1    a
1     2    b
2     3    c
3     4    a
4     5    b
```

How do i get an accurate mapping of the cat codes to cat categories?
The stackoverflow response below says to enumerate the categories. However, I'm not sure if enumerating was the way cat.codes generated the integer values. Is there a more accurate way?

[Get mapping of categorical variables in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510562/get-mapping-of-categorical-variables-in-pandas)

```
>>> dict( enumerate(df.five.cat.categories) )

{0: 'bad', 1: 'good'}
```

What is a good way to get the mapping in the above format but accurate?

Comment: FYI, I have since updated my answer (which you linked to) and added some explanation/verification.  I believe it is accurate although I'm happy to improve it if you can elaborate about what you think is inaccurate about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edited answer (removed `cat.categories` and changed `list` to `dict`):

```
>>> dict(zip(df_labels.col2.cat.codes, df_labels.col2))

{0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
```

The original answer which some of the comments are referring to:

```
>>> list(zip(df_labels.col2.cat.codes, df_labels.col2.cat.categories))

[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

As the comments note, the original answer works in this example because the first three values happend to be  `[a,b,c]`, but would fail if they were instead `[c,b,a]` or `[b,c,a]`.

Comment: Yes thanks! needed to put `set` in the front as i just want the unique mappings: `set(list(zip(df_labels.col2.cat.codes, df_labels.col2.cat.categories)))`

Comment: I think this answer only works because of the way col2 is ordered. `len(cat.categories)` is 3 while `len(cat.codes)` is 5.

Comment: This is an incorrect answer, because `ser.cat.categories` will return all the unique values in the category but not the corresponding label of the items in the series.

Comment: @JohnE feel free to edit. I cannot delete my answer for it is the accepted one

Comment: Thanks, @boud, I edited it (while preserving the original with a note).  Please add additional edits as you see fit.

Answer (score 6):

I use:

```
dict([(category, code) for code, category in enumerate(df_labels.col2.cat.categories)])

# {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```

Comment: Note that this is roughly equivalent to the answer rejected by the OP:   `dict(enumerate(df.five.cat.categories))` except that it switches keys and values from e.g. `0:'a'` to `'a':0` which is a minor difference as both keys and values here are unique so the key/value order is in some sense irrelevant and it's also easy enough to reverse.  (I think the answer (mine!) rejected by the OP is actually correct so I also think this one is correct too!)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to convert each column/ data series from categorical back to original, you just need to reverse what you did in the `for` loop of the dataframe. There are two methods to do that:

1. To get back to the original Series or numpy array, use `Series.astype(original_dtype)` or `np.asarray(categorical)`.
2. If you have already codes and categories, you can use the `from_codes()`constructor to save the factorize step during normal constructor mode.

See [pandas: Categorical Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html)

---

**Usage of `from_codes`**

As on [official documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.2/generated/pandas.core.categorical.Categorical.from_codes.html), it makes a Categorical type from codes and categories arrays.

```
splitter = np.random.choice([0,1], 5, p=[0.5,0.5])
s = pd.Series(pd.Categorical.from_codes(splitter, categories=["train", "test"]))
print splitter
print s
```

gives

```
[0 1 1 0 0]
0    train
1     test
2     test
3    train
4    train
dtype: category
Categories (2, object): [train, test]
```

For your codes

```
# after your previous conversion
print df['col2']
# apply from_codes, the 2nd argument is the categories from mapping dict
s = pd.Series(pd.Categorical.from_codes(df['col2'], list('abcde')))
print s
```

gives

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    0
4    1
Name: col2, dtype: int8
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
4    b
dtype: category
Categories (5, object): [a, b, c, d, e]
```

Comment: There is not much documentation about using `from_codes()`. Can you show me how i can apply it ?

Comment: I see, i just want the unique mapping values though, not the full mapping. For example { 0 : 'a', 1 : 'b',  2 : 'c' }

Comment: Then you can easily construct the map by yourself using codes and categories. Yet you cannot maintain the order by a Python dictionary, use two lists or a list of tuples in @Boud answer instead.

Answer (score 4):

OP asks for something "accurate" relative to the answer in the linked question:

```
dict(enumerate(df_labels.col2.cat.categories))

# {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
```

I believe that the above answer is indeed accurate (full disclosure: it is my answer in the other question that I'm defending).  Note also that it is roughly equivalent to @pomber's answer, except that the ordering of the keys and values is reversed.  (Since both keys and values are unique, the ordering is in some sense irrelevant, and easy enough to reverse as a consequence).

However, the following way is arguably safer, or at least more transparent as to how it works:

```
dict(zip(df_labels.col2.cat.codes, df_labels.col2))

# {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}
```

This is similar in spirit to @boud's answer, but corrects an error by replacing `df_labels.col2.cat.codes` with `df_labels.col2`.  It also replaces `list()` with `dict()` which seems more appropriate for a mapping and automatically gets rid of duplicates.

Note that the length of both arguments to `zip()` is `len(df)`, whereas the length of `df_labels.col2.cat.categories` is a count of unique values which will generally be much shorter than `len(df)`.

Also note that this method is quite inefficient as it maps `0` to `'a'` twice, and similarly for `'b'`.  In large dataframes the difference in speed could be pretty big.  But it won't cause any error because `dict()` will remove redundancies like this -- it's just that it will be much less efficient than the other method.