# Pandas categorical data: Storing the transformation

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, categorical-data

Say I have the following dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5], 'col2':list('abcab'),  'col3':list('ababb')})
```

I can convert the categorical data into integers by doing the following.

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype('category')
df['col3'] = df['col3'].astype('category')
cat_columns = df.select_dtypes(['category']).columns
df[cat_columns] = df[cat_columns].apply(lambda x: x.cat.codes)
```

At the end of this transformation when I do print(df.dtypes), I get

```
col1    int64
col2     int8
col3     int8
```

All the categorical information is missing. Can I save the category-to-integer mapping in a file? I want to be able to programmatically invert the transformation on the dataframe at a future time.

EDIT: I am looking for a reversible process. So that means saving down in an actual file, the transformations for all the categorical columns. At some future time, I want to take whatever results I have, where the columns will still have the same name as the original dataframe, do the inverse transformation using the saved information and get the results in terms of categorical data.

Comment: you obliterated the category dtype when you applied to get the codes.

Comment: How do I save it  before I do the cat.codes? I am open to inserting an additional operation before I obliterate the category dtype. I just want a reversible process.

Comment: What is the aim of this transformation - is this as part of machine learning?

Comment: @KRKirov, that's one possible use.

Comment: Most machine learning algorithms don't work directly with categorically encoded data, but with one-hot encoded data. Label encoding is typically used only for encoding the y data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a couple of nested dictionary comprehensions to store your mappings in both directions for all category columns. If you need to store these externally, you can use `pickle`.

```
cat_cols = df.select_dtypes(['category']).columns

cat_to_code = {col: dict(zip(df[col], df[col].cat.codes)) \
               for col in cat_cols}
# {'col2': {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}, 'col3': {'a': 0, 'b': 1}}

code_to_cat = {k: {v2: k2 for k2, v2 in v.items()} \
               for k, v in cat_to_code.items()}
# {'col2': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c'}, 'col3': {0: 'a', 1: 'b'}}

df[cat_cols] = df[cat_cols].apply(lambda x: x.cat.codes)
```

Note that 2-way injective mappings are not possible natively, you'll have to maintain 2 separate mappings if you need O(1) access in both directions.

Comment: There is an issue with the cat_to_code. If 'col2':list('aabca'), you will see that this is wrong. The cat.codes gives the translated column (length=5), but cat.categories gives only unique categories, length=3.

Comment: @Spinor8, Woops, `enumerate` should work instead, have updated.

Comment: Are we always guaranteed that the code is generated from enumerate? We use enumerate for the mapping cat_to_code but the actual mapping we used is cat.codes. I just worried one day Pandas might decide to enumerate from say 1, instead of 0, and we have all this code starting from zero.

Comment: I don't see it documented. But it's the upvoted solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510562/get-mapping-of-categorical-variables-in-pandas) and makes theoretical sense.

Comment: I think a safer bet might be to use something like this in place of the last line. for col in cat_cols: df[col].map(code_to_cat[col]). That way you are not assuming anything. You are using all the mappings that you've generated yourself.

Comment: @Spinor8, OK, this should work now, we can just use `zip` with `df[col]` and `df[col].cat.codes`, a bit messy but the docs are also messy.

Comment: I see what you are doing. This is the cleanest while still using Panda's cat.codes. Cute!