# Why does a Random Forest take longer to fit a dataframe with dummy variables?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am taking the fastai [Intro to Machine Learning course](http://course18.fast.ai/ml), and in [Lesson 1](http://course18.fast.ai/lessonsml1/lesson1.html) he uses a Random Forest on the [Blue Book for Bulldozers dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/bluebook-for-bulldozers/data) from Kaggle.

In a curious move to me the instructor did not use `pd.get_dummies()` or `OneHotEncoder` from SKlearn to handle categorical data.  Instead he called `pd.Series.cat.codes` on all categorical columns.

I noticed when the`fit()` method was called, it computed much faster (about 1 minute) on the dataset using `pd.Series.cat.codes`, whereas the dataset with the dummy variables crashed on a virtual server I had running that was using 60 GB of RAM.

The memory each dataframe occupied was about the same........54 MB.  I'm curious why one dataframe is so much more performant than the other?

Is it because with a single column of integers a Random Forest only considers the average of that column as its cut point, thus making it easier to compute?  Or is it something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510562/get-mapping-of-categorical-variables-in-pandas is a nice explanation of cat.codes with example.

Answer (score 1):

To understand this better we need to look at the working of Tree based models. In a tree based algo the data is split into bins based on feature and its values. The splitting algorithm considers all possible splits and learns the most optimal split (Minimized impurity of resulting bins).

When we consider continuous numeric feature for a split, then there would be a number of combination on which a tree can split.
Categorical features are disadvantaged and have only a few options for splitting which results in a very sparse decision trees. This becomes worse for category with just two levels.

Also dummy variables are created to avoid the model from learning false ordinality. Since tree based model works on the principle of splitting this is not an issue and there is no need to create dummy variables.

Answer (score 0):

pd.get_dummies will add k (or k-1 if drop_first = True) columns to your DataFrame. In case of a very large K, the RandomForest algorithm as more choice to make when sub-selecting the features thus making each tree training longer to train.

You could use the max_features parameters to limit the number of feature used during each tree training but the scikit-learn implementation of the algorithm doesn't take into account that your dummies variable are actually from one feature, meaning it could select only a subset of dummies from your categorical variable

This could lead to sub-performance of your model. I'm guessing this is why `fastai` uses
`pd.Series.cat.codes`.