# How do I create another column with value of different elements in a column?

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame object like this

```
ColumnOne |  ColumnTwo
ABCD      |  red
ABCD      |  blue
EFGH      |  green
IJKL      |  white
```

I want a DataFrame object like this

```
ColumnOne |  ColumnTwo | ColumnThree
ABCD      |  red       | 0
ABCD      |  blue      | 0
EFGH      |  green     | 1
IJKL      |  white     | 2
```

based on ColumnOne elements, how do I do this?

Comment: What is the logic behind numbers in column three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `pd.factorize()`. From the docs: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html

Passing a `Series` to `pd.factorize()` returns two arrays: `labels` and `uniques`. `labels` is a numeric encoding of your categories, and `uniques` is an array of unique values in the `Series` you just passed in. So you can discard `uniques` and just assign `labels` to a new column like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ColumnOne': ['ABCD', 'ABCD', 'EFGH', 'IJKL'],
    'ColumnTwo': ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'white']
})

# factorize returns (labels, uniques) and you just want labels
df['ColumnThree'] = pd.factorize(df['ColumnOne'])[0]
```

Alternatively, if you convert `df['ColumnOne']` to the `categorical` dtype, you can use any of the answers from this other post:
[Get mapping of categorical variables in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510562/get-mapping-of-categorical-variables-in-pandas)