# Mapping of multiple columns categorical values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose that I have a dataframe with three columns with categorical data, and I want to transform the three categorical columns into a single value and map to the original dataframe. I understand that this is possible with a single column with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510562/get-mapping-of-categorical-variables-in-pandas), but how about multiple columns?

Example: From this

```
>>>df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['0', '1', '2', '3','4'],
...                   'x':['tall', 'short', 'tall', 'short', 'tall'],
...                   'y':['fat', 'thin', 'thin', 'fat', 'fat'],
...                   'z':['male', 'female', 'female', 'male', 'male']},
...                   dtype='category')

>>>df
  id      x     y       z
0  0   tall   fat    male
1  1  short  thin  female
2  2   tall  thin  female
3  3  short   fat    male
4  4   tall   fat    male
```

to this by mapping with the columns: x, y and z

```
>>>df
  id      x     y       z  map
0  0   tall   fat    male    0
1  1  short  thin  female    1
2  2   tall  thin  female    2
3  3  short   fat    male    3
4  4   tall   fat    male    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is `groupby().ngroup()`:

```
df['map'] = df.groupby(['x','y','z'], sort=False).ngroup()
```

Or, if your data are string type, you can concatenate the columns, possibly with some special character, and use the single column approach:

```
# add('&') may not be needed
df['map'] = pd.factorize(df[['x','y','z']].add('&').sum(1))[0]
```

Output:

```
   id      x     y       z  map
0   0   tall   fat    male    0
1   1  short  thin  female    1
2   2   tall  thin  female    2
3   3  short   fat    male    3
4   4   tall   fat    male    0
```